# Is there a virtualizing WrapPanel for WPF available? Commercial or free ones

Tags: wpf, wrappanel

Is there a virtualizing WrapPanel available? Commercial or free ones.

I have seen some blogs (dan's included) but it does not seem to work well in my application, especially when i have child items of varying sizes.

Also even with same size those free ones do not work well.

Are there any commercial ones available in the market? I cannot find any.

Please comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a commercial one i would say try Binarymission
I can't post a link since i am new user, but if you google for "binarymission" you will get there. Its a commercial WPF + Winforms UI library web site.

Comment: Hey, great! :-) Thanks for that. I purchased their suite... its a bit costly, but i got the virtialising wrappanel. Exactly what i was looking for :-)

In fact i was looking for a multi-column combobox control for a long time, and they had it in the pack along with several other controls.
You saved my day Man. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is also :

http://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com/ which is free (MIT License)

and

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VirtualizingWrapPanel.aspx which is free too (Code Project Open License (CPOL))